# How can I insert another row into another table, in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I can insert the list of questions but the problem is the answer? How

```
  $myQuery= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblquestion, tblanswer WHERE questionID='$ctrlnum'"); 
  $numRows = mysql_num_rows($myQuery);
```

then this will be the insertion of record:

```
$myQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblquestion VALUES ( '$ctrlnum','$question1','$question2','$question3','$question4','$question5',
'$question6','$question7','$question8','$question9','$question10') "); 

$myQuery= mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblprelimanswer VALUES ('$ctrlnum','$answer1','$answer2','$answer3','$answer4','$answer5', '$answer6','$answer7','$answer8','$answer9','$answer10')
");
```

How can I insert the answers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I am afraid we will need to see more code and a detailed description of what you expect this to do and what it is actually doing / not doing.

Comment: And what's the error you got? What are the values? Did you try escaping the strings?

Comment: Tips: 1. don't shout in your title (I fixed this and downvoted). 2. Format your code using the formatting tools provided (fixed). 3. Don't use txtspk, it is likely to get you more downvotes (fixed). 4. Explain what your problem is in detail. What doesn't work with your `INSERT` query?

Comment: I cant post the code im a newbie here..this site are prompting messages that I need to format my code but its sooo long..my question is..is t possible to use double insert to add record in different table? insert for the tblquestions (well ..it work) and insert for tblanswer (w/c didnt work) btw thanks for the response...

Comment: Can you help me with this? I badly really need it for tomorrow.. again using two INSERT statement? is it possible ? insert for tblquestion and insert for the tblanswer.. only 1 did work..

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
$myQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblquestion VALUES ($ctrlnum','$question1','$question2','$question3','$question4','$question5','$question6','$question7','$question8','$question9','$question10') ") or die (mysql_error()); 

$myQuery= mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblprelimanswer VALUES ('$ctrlnum','$answer1','$answer2','$answer3','$answer4','$answer5', '$answer6','$answer7','$answer8','$answer9','$answer10')") or die (mysql_error());
```

and post back what your error messages are

Comment: OMG!! Thank  you so much !! IT did work!! THANK YOU AgeDeO <3 :) YOU'RE AMAZING! SOO HAPPY THAT MY PROBLEM WAs SOLVED! THANK YOU SO MUCH! xD THANKS FOR THE EFFORT! THANK YOU <3

Comment: I am glad I could help you, but there is a lot wrong with the way you are querying in your database. please listen to the advice from other users like symcbean to make your code safe and futureproof

Comment: Yea, maybe thats why  im also having a hard time with my system, but anyway thank you so much! It was the last error that I have to get rid and thanks to you guys that I did soo lucky to knew this site and posted then met you AgeDeo and symcbean :) I really appreciate you two for being such a good person ..for helping me..it was part of my final requirements :D THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

(This should be a comment but its rather long and easier to read with formatting)

While using a statement of the form

```
INSERT INTO tblquestion VALUES (...)
```

will work in MySQL, it is very bad practice not to explicitly state what columns each value maps to. e.g.

```
 INSERT INTO tblquestion ( someId, avalue, adifferentthing ) VALUES (...)
```

In the relational database model, there is no concept of oredering of attributes within a record. Even on MySQL where such an approach is possible, semantic value is lost by omitting the atribute list and there is a risk of bugs being introduced if the schema is modified.

Further:

```
'$question1','$question2','$question3','$question4','$question5'....
```

implies that your data is not normalized. Each question should be in a seperate row.

Comment: Thank you symcbean, I WILL :) Thank you for your effort and for the help :) Thnk you soo much guys.. Im so thankful that you did response :) Again, Thank you symcbean :D <3